# How to group data and make a custom JSON object from the array retrieved by query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a table and grouped data, which is mentioned below:

[image]

I want to generate a json like the one below. What procedures do I need to follow?

[image]

Comment: Please add all code and attempts to your question (not as images).

Comment: @incredibleHat, I have not attempted to generate the json, as I am confused to do it

Comment: Actually the problem got solved, I changed the parsing of data differently from the JS Code.